# reading in certain rows from a csv file using python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, canopy

Say I have a csv file that looks like the following with the first column containing frequencies and the second column containing the power level (dBm).

```
Frequency | dBm

1           -11.43
2.3         -51.32
2.5         -12.11
2.8         -11.21
3.1         -73.22
3.2         -21.13
```

I only want to read in the data sets of this file that have a (dBm) value between -13 and -10. Therefore, in this example I only want the data sets (1, -11.43)(2.5, -12.11)(2.8, -11.21) to be read into my program variables x1 and y1. Could someone give me some help in how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library and check if each meets your criteria.

Something like this should work on your file:

```
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=' ')
        reader.next()
        reader.next()
        for row in reader:
                a = [float(i) for i in row if i!='']
        if a[1]>=-13 and a[1]<=-1:
            print (a[0],a[1])
```

**Edit:** If you're working with table data I would suggest trying out [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), it's really helpful in these situations.

Comment: thanks for this! However, I was hoping for an example of how I might achieve this.

Comment: made an example that works on your example file, you might have to tweak it for your real data

Comment: do you know what the library name of the csv toolbox is called? I search for csv in the package manager for Canopy and cannot find anything

Comment: It's part of python, if you have python installed you can just import it with: "import csv"

Comment: Joao do you know what this error is saying. Its pointing to the line that contains the a = [float(i) for i in row if i!='']                 Error is invalid literal for float(): 2.00E+09,1.10E+01